# Dynamically access methods of class TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties

I'm trying to access the methods of a class dynamically, using the value of a previously set variable in TypeScript.

Something similar to this:

```js
class Foo {
    bar(){ }
}

var methodName = "bar";
var fooBar = new Foo();

fooBar.methodName(); // I would like this to resolve to fooBar.bar();
```

For example in PHP  I can do the following:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar(){ }
}

$methodName = "bar";
$fooBar = new Foo();

$fooBar.$methodName(); // resolves to fooBar.bar();
```

Anyone know if this is possible, and if it is, how to do it?
I know it slightly contradicts the idea of a typed language, but its the only solution to my current problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We simply have to leave strongly typed *(and checked)* world, and use just a JavaScript style *(which is still useful, e.g. in these cases)*

```
fooBar[methodName]();
```

Comment: That's awesome!
In addition, if you're calling a method from within a class its this[methodName]();

Answer (score 1):

I believe an [interface](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/interfaces#classes-can-implement-interfaces) will sort you out here...

```js
interface FooInterface {
  bar: () => void
  // ...other methods
}

class Foo implements FooInterface {
  bar() {
    console.log('bar')
  }
  // .. other methods omitted
}

const foo = new Foo()

// good 
foo['bar']

// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"barry"' can't be used to index type 'Foo'.
//  Property 'barry' does not exist on type 'Foo'.
foo['barry']

let method: keyof FooInterface

// good
method = 'bar'
foo[method]()

// Type '"barry"' is not assignable to type 'keyof FooInterface'.
method = 'barry'
foo[method]()
```

You can play with this example in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIBiB7bBJaeZNdAb1HXQCMk4AudACgEp0BeAPnQDdswATCugD0w9ADpJ2KAAt46ALYxZ2fgGdQAX1CgUAGyRq1WXOjAKADnphLoxnPkKJUGciEo04LMkMopsEGrY1uJ62ADmjADknlHMQtruImKS6NJycIrKMqrG2ApgULCCIIm6AWpQ6AimbOgQMADuJtgsoNZVSir8DADWMACe2AgtBLDOaDogoujhuPzooDXYANoxtFEAulMzAKLWtlXmVmAohXoD6DKG6EgQ6FF3A1HoUAMWGFQwKEgArmoYGAADwscBgRjAATSIzeHweACJPHABvCXj8IFEql90P8YAsoNgzBB%20MDXu8MFEHFFxKAZugAApwbAfOBvB5I57ofjYcH1aToYFgSppe6wilUmkgZZrDlbHZiJB6PSzeagLo5BZ1dZwKJLXArdWqTZtEC0sQAFXJCI5qLMxgg-MMajA4QgSCo1lehLFD36QxGDjGRBc1LV2VU7HZtGRuql%20sN-GN8VNICAA).

I'm learning in public here, so hopefully someone might refine this further one day

> I'm trying to access the methods of a class dynamically, using the value of a previously set variable in TypeScript.

I'm reading this as "I know what the class methods are at compile time"; if you're actually trying to generate class methods at runtime, maybe the voodoo in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259904/2586761 might help!

Comment: *I know this is an old question - that's what the [necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) badge is for!* 