# Dynamic class methods

Tags: typescript

Does anyone have a good fix on getting type checking when extending a class with dynamic methods? For example say you want to extend the class with methods based on options passed to the constructor. This is common in plain ol' JavaScript.

```
const defaults = {
  dynamicMethods: ['method1', 'method2'];
};

class Hello {
  constructor(options) {
    options.dynamicMethods.forEach(m => this[m] = this.common);
  }
  private common(...args: any[]) {
     // do something.
  }
}

const hello = new Hello(defaults);
```

Of course the above will work and you'll be able to call these dynamic methods but you won't get intellisense.

Not you can solve this problem with something like the below:

```
class Hello<T> {
  constructor(options) {
    options.dynamicMethods.forEach(m => this[m] = this.common);
  }
  private common(...args: any[]) {
     // do something.
  }
}

interface IMethods {
  method1(...args: any[]);
  method2(...args: any[]);
}

function Factory<T>(options?): T & Hello<T> {
  const hello = new Hello<T>(options);
  return hello as T & Hello<T>;
}
```

To consume this:

```
import { Factory } from './some/path'
const hello = new Factory<IMethods>(defaults);
```

This of course works but wondering what other alternatives exist!

Comment: Why do you need to mutate the class definition in runtime?

Comment: Take for example a logger. You might have an error, warn and info methods but what if user wants to add additional methods? For example user wants to add a verbose method. You can bind the method well enough but you'll get and error as TypeScript will complain about that method as it won't know about it.

Comment: "what if user wants to add additional methods" --- then what you want wouldn't be type-safe. `logger.log(level, message)`

Comment: Not correct, if you mixin an interface you'll get type checking just fine. You could even do `type Constructor<T, U> = new(...args: any[]) => T & U` Then just pass in an interface and class as your generics and all is well. Again works fine wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: "Then just pass in an interface" --- what *interface*? You mentioned a user to add *arbitrary* methods in runtime. Please change your example to acomodate a method with a name unknown at compile time.

Comment: I think you are already using the best solution TypeScript has for extending types (intersection types and type assertions), although I would tighten up your code (`options` should be typed, and the `T` in `Hello<T>` isn't doing anything for you).  What's bad about it that you are looking to improve?

Comment: It already shows the interface. see `IMethods` so no there's nothing to update.

Comment: @jcalz yes the options are typed ha ha ur picky. Just left it out for brevity sake. Just was wondering if there was a more efficient way and I honestly can't think of one.

Answer (score 7):

After playing around with this a bit I came up with something that doesn't require declaring an interface for each extension:

```
interface ClassOf<T> {
  new(...args: any[]) : T
}

const extendClass = <T,S>(class_ : ClassOf<T>, dynamicMethods : S) =>
  (...args: any[]) => {
    const o = new class_(args) as T & S;
    for (const key of Object.keys(dynamicMethods) as Array<keyof S>) {
      const method = dynamicMethods[key];
      (o as S)[key] = method; // type sig seems unnecessary
    }
  return o;
}

// demo:
class Hello {
  constructor(public name) {}

  hello() {
    return 'hello ' + this.name;
  }
}

const extHelloConstr = extendClass(Hello, {incr: (x : number) => x + 1, show: (n : number) => 'nr ' + n});
const extHello = extHelloConstr('jimmy');
const test1 = extHello.incr(1);
const test2 = extHello.show(42);
const test3 = extHello.hello();
console.log(test1, test2, test3);
```

[playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ClassOf%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20new(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20extendClass%20%3D%20%3CT%2CS%3E(class_%20%3A%20ClassOf%3CT%3E%2C%20dynamicMethods%20%3A%20S)%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20o%20%3D%20new%20class_(args)%20as%20T%20%26%20S%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20key%20of%20Object.keys(dynamicMethods)%20as%20Array%3Ckeyof%20S%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20method%20%3D%20dynamicMethods%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(o%20as%20S)%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20method%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20sig%20seems%20unnecessary%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20return%20o%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20demo%3A%0D%0Aclass%20Hello%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20name)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20hello()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'hello%20'%20%2B%20this.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20extHelloConstr%20%3D%20extendClass(Hello%2C%20%7Bincr%3A%20(x%20%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%201%2C%20show%3A%20(n%20%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20'nr%20'%20%2B%20n%7D)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20extHello%20%3D%20extHelloConstr('jimmy')%3B%0D%0Aconst%20test1%20%3D%20extHello.incr(1)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20extHello.show(42)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20extHello.hello()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test1%2C%20test2%2C%20test3)%3B)

Except for the constructor arguments (which seem tricky,) all inferred types are correct. It even works when the code is executed. You can also return an anonymous class, but it's a bit weird to type those.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but perhaps it can serve as a source of inspiration.

Comment: I have to say I find this code quite unreadable (its intention is unclear from just reading the code). You're jumping through a lot of hoops to allow something that's not a good idea to begin with (in my opinion). The difference between TS and JS is not just syntax, it's also about design.

Comment: @kokodoko I find Oblosys code completely readable. I think the prob here is this is an advanced issue and many commenting here seem to not understand these more involved use cases. Not taking shots at you here just saying there's nothing wrong with this example.

Comment: That's ok, discussion is good! I encounter a lot of cases where a design problem is not recognized and instead the dev tries to work around it with some very smart code. This happens especially in JS, which is a very loose language that allows almost anything :)

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way. Use `Object.assign` method:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    const dynamic_property_name = "hello_world"

    Object.assign(this, {
      [dynamic_property_name]: "new value"
    })
  }
}

console.log(new Test())
```

**Output**

```sh
Test { hello_world: 'new value' }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you can get rid of the `IMethods` interface and use the `Record` type.

```
class Hello {
  constructor(options: string[]) {
    options.forEach(m => this[m] = this.common);
  }
  private common(...args: any[]) {
     // do something.
  }
}

function Factory<T extends string>(...options: T[]): Hello & Record<T, (...args) => any[]> {
  const hello = new Hello(options);
  return hello as Hello & Record<T, (...args) => any[]>;
}

const hello = Factory("method1", "method2");
hello.method1();
hello.method2();
```

Comment: Forgot about "Record". I have some chaining going on as well. At first blush everything implied will prob. just work going this route. Will try, but this looks like a solid solution.

Comment: BTW this won't work with the return type for the factory. You need to leave it implied or create a custom Type and set it and the class as the return Type. Otherwise you just get the methods and not the class.

Comment: Added the `Hello` class in the return type. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yeah but you don't really need the return type in both places. Will be implied but doesn't hurt. Kinda of took ur reminder on Record here and ran with that. You're totally right on that thinking as it prevents need for interface/object etc. Maybe I should post solution then you can edit yours and we'll mark as "accepted", thoughts?

Comment: Sure. Lets have the question answered.

Comment: this code does not compile.  on line 3, `this[m]`, i receive `[ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Hello' has no index signature.`.  this is consistent with what i have observed when trying to extend a prototype dynamically as well

Answer (score 0):

Heavily inspired by @Oblosys's answer, but this solution also supports static methods from the original class via inheritance, avoids `any`, and returns a constructible class rather than a function (which can't be called with `new` in TS). It can also be extended indefinitely, so you could have many different plugins extend a logger and then still allow the user to extend it themselves.

```js
// A simple type that allows extending the given class with given non-static methods
// We can type arguments to the constructor as an array, e.g. `[string]`
// This isn't amazingly clean, but it works
type ExtendedClass<Class, Methods, ArgsType extends unknown[] = []> = {
    new (...args: ArgsType): Class & Methods;
};

class DynamicallyExtendableClass {
    constructor(private name: string) {}

    static testMethod() {
        return "Blah";
    }

    dependent() {
        return `Hello ${this.name}!`;
    }

    // We use a static method here because it doesn't refer to `this` (see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this)
    static extend<Methods>(
        newMethods: Methods
    ): ExtendedClass<DynamicallyExtendableClass, Methods, [string]> &
        typeof DynamicallyExtendableClass {
        // We create a new class that extends the class we're going to add new methods to
        class Class extends this {
            constructor(name: string) {
                super(name);
                // Then we assign those methods to the class's `this`
                // This is all we need in JS, but TS won't support these types yet
                Object.assign(this, newMethods);
            }
        }
        // We convert the class's type based off the original class, extending with the new methods
        // Finally, we add support for the static non-instance methods with `& typeof Class`
        return Class as ExtendedClass<Class, Methods, [string]> & typeof Class;
    }
}

// We can extend it with new methods
const Extended = DynamicallyExtendableClass.extend({
    method1: (num: number) => num,
    method2: (str: string) => str,
});
// Which gives us a new fully-fledged class
const ext = new Extended("Name");
const test1 = ext.method1(500);
const test2 = ext.method2("Test");

// ext.method3(); // This would throw a TypeScript error

// We have access to the static methods of the original class by inheritance
const test3 = Extended.testMethod();
// And we can extend as many times as we want!
const ExtExt = Extended.extend({
    blah: (str: string) => `Blah: ${str}`,
});
const test4 = new ExtExt("Name").blah("Test");
console.log(test1, test2, test3, test4, new ExtExt("Name").dependent()); // Outputs: `500 Test Blah Blah: Test`
```